# Currently, calling the connections api with the public-profile-url is causing an internal server error

Tags: linkedin-api

Currently (but not usually), if you call the following url you get an internal server error:
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,headline,picture-url,summary,first-name,last-name,formatted-name,location:(name),industry,positions,num-connections,num-connections-capped,api-standard-profile-request:(url,headers),public-profile-url)?format=json

Remove the public-profile-url and call the following url, it works:
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,headline,picture-url,summary,first-name,last-name,formatted-name,location:(name),industry,positions,num-connections,num-connections-capped,api-standard-profile-request:(url,headers))?format=json

Why?

Comment: Probably a side effect of LinkedIn overhauling their API. Anyway, thanks for pointing out that the public profile url field was the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They seemed to have reduced the number of contacts you can get each time you request them.  I used to ask for 500 and it worked for a long time, and then last week it stopped working and instead would return:

```
 <status>500</status>
 <timestamp>1424451457253</timestamp>
 <request-id>HISKBDLSOA</request-id>
 <error-code>0</error-code>
 <message>Internal service error</message>
```

Now, I request 250 contacts each time and it works again.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(public-profile-url)?start=0&count=250&modified=updated
```