# Getting Public-Profile-URL of connections gives me 500 error

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I have a premium account but if i want to get the information of my connections it gives me an 500 error

This is the original call

```
~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,industry,phone-numbers,location:(name),picture-urls::(original),date-of-birth,positions,skills,certifications,educations,public-profile-url,connections:(id,first-name,last-name,public-profile-url,picture-urls::(original),positions:(title,is-current,company,start-date)))
```

This works fine

```
~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,industry,phone-numbers,location:(name),picture-urls::(original),date-of-birth,positions,skills,certifications,educations,public-profile-url,connections:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-urls::(original),positions:(title,is-current,company,start-date)))
```

The only difference is that "public-profile-url" is not in the connections parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are experiencing the same error. It seems that this error is a duplication of [Currently, calling the connections api with the public-profile-url is causing an internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521988/currently-calling-the-connections-api-with-the-public-profile-url-is-causing-an). So this is a problem that is already present since yesterday.

EDIT: the error is not generated for every LinkedIn user. I am not able to distinguish why it is failing for some users.

EDIT: the error is only generated for the logged in user, not for people queries.