# Linkedin connections API 'public-profile-url' throwing 500 error

Tags: linkedin-api

The same thing seems to have happened two years ago [public-profile-url causing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521988/currently-calling-the-connections-api-with-the-public-profile-url-is-causing-an), but the approved solution on that question is not solving this problem.

Any connections requests requesting the field 'public-profile-url' throws the following error:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(public-profile-url)?start=0&oauth2_access_token=<token>

<error>
<status>500</status>
<timestamp>1491329264595</timestamp>
<request-id>8IJSBKJHQR</request-id>
<error-code>0</error-code>
<message>Internal API server error</message>
</error>
```

If this is just an issue with their API, I'd love to get LinkedIn's attention on the matter.

**Edit**: Interestingly, I found a specific Linkedin connection that is causing the failure (by adjusting the 'start' and 'count' args). It's probably not wise to post that here, but I can provide that information to LinkedIn staff, if need be.

**Edit 2**: I found replacing 'public-profile' with 'site-standard-profile-request' does function as a workaround. It's not exactly the same thing, but close enough if your user is already using oauth

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, in my case solved removing the "site-standard-profile-request" and the "current-share" attributes from the linkedin v1 people request.

Here is the working api url:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,maiden-name,formatted-name,phonetic-first-name,phonetic-last-name,formatted-phonetic-name,headline,location,industry,num-connections,num-connections-capped,summary,specialties,positions,picture-url,picture-urls::(original),site-standard-profile-request,api-standard-profile-request)
```